# Communicate different pods using Podman

Tags: linux, networking, namespaces, podman

I am deploying several Pods using podman-compose. To do so, each pod has its own definition in a podman-compose.yaml file that I execute in rootless mode (so all containers in a Pod coexist in the same host/IP). However, I would like to make able a container in a Pod to reach a service exposed by a container in another pod.

I know Kubernetes has the Service object that let pods communicate between them. But I don't want to use K8S...

**So my question is**: Is there any 'equivalent' or workaround I could use to reach such a communication between pods? Not only in the Podman ecosystem, but in the Linux's one.

Ideally, I would like to use a DNS that lets containers resolve the IP of other containers in other pods. Should I use my machine (where all pods are running) DNS to proxy requests between pods? And more importantly, is this a good practice?

Sorry if the answer is pretty obvios, I am new in the IT world.

Anyway, thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a network and have all the pods use that network on start.  Then if you use --name to name the pods, be able to use that name as the DNS entry from others.

Eg

```
podman network create $NETWORK_NAME

podman pod create --name $POD1 --network $NETWORK_NAME

podman pod create --name $POD2 --network $NETWORK_NAME

podman run -it --detach --pod $POD1 --name $CONTAINER1 --network $NETWORK_NAME image_name

podman run -it --detach --pod $POD2 --name $CONTAINER2 --network $NETWORK_NAME image_name
```

now if you were curling from CONTAINER2, you could use
curl http://$POD1 and it would resolve to the IP (private ip on the network created) for that POD.

If you dont want to use pods, just remove all pod create and --pod flags to podman run, and instead use $CONTAINER1 or $CONTAINER2 to talk to the other containers in the same network.

With this, you dont need to expose a load of ports, and have your containers communicate to the host and back to the exposed port.  Just reference them by pod / container name.

Comment: In my experience, it only works when also specifying `--hostname $SOMENAME` when creating a pod. This is also possible directly with e.g. `podman run --detach --pod new:$POD1 --name $CONTAINER1 --hostname $POD1 --network $NETWORK_NAME image_name`.

Comment: What is the effect of binding the network to both pod and container?

Comment: I tried this approach, and the container in a pod has problem communicating with other containers in the same pod who don't attach the network. Of course I can attach the network to all containers, but that seems unnecessary.

Comment: __Disclaimer__: I didn't try it yet, I'm just asking. 
Is it really necessary to specify the network when running the `podman run` command? In [this article](https://codeberg.org/wolfangaukang/blog/src/branch/master/pod-to-pod-communication-with-podman.md), the `podman pod create` is the command attaching the network, not the `podman run` ones.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found out in the [containers organization](https://github.com/containers) the Podman's [dnsname plugin](https://github.com/containers/dnsname) that makes possible the pod to pod resolution by using its DNS gateway.

Comment: This plugin has been deprecated. I am unsure what to do alternatively.

Comment: I see. What about [netavark](https://github.com/containers/netavark/) or [aardvark-dns](https://github.com/containers/aardvark-dns/)?

Comment: Yes, those 2 packages helped me solve the problem :) Thanks Hector.